# Magento 2 Configurable Product Out of memory

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, memory-leak

We have been using Ubertheme to transfer our magento1 store to magento2.  Everything seems to be working correctly, except when we go to a configurable product (backend or frontend), the Magento2 server spikes and start using all the memory on the server.

```
Wed Mar 13 14:12:34.051050 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2860] [client 173.49.71.23:61885] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 6585057280 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 979, referer:
```

The error changes between frontend and backend.  We had tried a 4GB RAM instance and then tried a 8GB Ram instance.

There are absolutely no other errors in either the Apache log folder or Magento var/log.

UPDATE: Here are the last lines from the profiler

```
"magento->LAYOUT->layout_render->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml->TTT4:Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\Collection::_afterLoad",0.001798,0.001798,1,"9,848",0
magento->LAYOUT->layout_render->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml->EVENT:magento_catalog_api_data_productinterface_load_after,0.007284,0.007284,1,"13,968",0
magento->LAYOUT->layout_render->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml->EVENT:magento_catalog_api_data_productinterface_load_after->OBSERVER:legacy_model_load,0.007270,0.007270,1,"12,344",0
magento->LAYOUT->layout_render->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml->EVENT:magento_catalog_api_data_productinterface_load_after->OBSERVER:legacy_model_load->EVENT:catalog_product_load_after,0.006344,0.006344,1,"9,016",0
magento->LAYOUT->layout_render->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml->TEMPLATE:/var/www/new.instantprecieux.fr/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml->EVENT:magento_catalog_api_data_productinterface_load_after->OBSERVER:legacy_model_load->EVENT:catalog_product_load_after->OBSERVER:inventory,0.006331,0.006331,1,"7,416",0
```

Comment: Have you checked exception log?

Comment: Yes, as I said, there are no errors in the web of magento var/log folders.

Comment: Looks like some code is running recursively. Do you have any custom or third party module installed?

Comment: Nothing.  Vanilla instance of Magento2

Comment: What version of Magento2? Have you tried migrating data with the magento data migration tool? It will take a bit of effort, but if your configurable products work with the migration tool I'd contact Ubertheme (assuming you're using their migration tool). https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the "catalog_product_super_link" table for configurable products, had a link to itself.  Not sure if that was normal or not, but in Magento 1 it didn't make any difference.  When it was migrated to Magento2, it caused some sort of infinite loop in both the admin interface and the frontend.

```
Delete From catalog_product_super_link Where parent_id = 9106 and product_id = 9106;
```

You have to find each wrong product and delete it manually.

[image: Magento2 catalog_product_super_link]